# Kubernetes pre-delete hook blocks helm delete if deployment fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, cloud, kubernetes-helm

In my helm chart, there's a pre-delete job that removes some extra resources when doing `helm delete`. If the deployment goes well, there's no problem with it.

However, when errors happen such as `imagePullBackoff` or `pvc unbounded`, the pre-delete job still try to execute and will go into error state as well so that the `helm delete` will time out.

I understand there's a `helm delete --no-hook` option, but i can't change the delete button in UI to make it happen as it's provided by third party.

Is there anything that I can do in my chart so that the `helm delete` automatically doesn't wait for pre-delete job if the job failed?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to write your `pre-delete` hook Job in a way that it will always reports success no matter what happened during the execution of main operation.

Example:

```
$ cat success.sh:

ls sdfsf || exit 0

$ cat success2.sh

set +e
ls 
ls sdfsf
exit 0
```

The scripts `success.sh` and `success2.sh` always return `0` (success), despite that `ls sdfsf` command inside the scripts returns `2` ("No such file or directory" error).

```
# following command also has exit code 0
$ ls sfsdf || echo -n ''
```

Comment: But when the job is in error state (for example, ImagePullBackOff), the bash script wouldn't even be executed

Comment: In this case you can pull required images in advance and change ImagePullPolicy in the Job to IfNotPresent

Comment: I can do this but customers can't do this through backend lol. Thanks for the suggestions though